# PHP - Dynamic Class Name Inside Class Properties

Tags: php, class, dynamic, properties, static

I was wondering if it's possible to dynamically access a static class from within a class property. I'm trying to access the properties in a nchild class, but I'm having to do something like this:

```
$error = $this->errorClass;
$error::myMethod ();
```

What I really want to do is this:

```
$this->errorClass::myMethod ();
```

I keep getting *PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '::'* If this isn't possible, does anybody know of a somewhat similar way to do things that doesn't involve repeating myself for every class/method? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->errorClass::myMethod();
```

Please explain to the parser what you want? `$temp = errorClass::myMethod(); $this->$temp;` or `$temp = $this->errorClass; $temp::myMethod();`.

Because of such problems this is impossible.

The shortest you can use (1 single statement...) is:

```
${'_'.!$this->errorClass}::myMethod();
```